# Settings Admob Parameters- Android

Tags: android, admob

I've set Admob in my android app,and I noticed the option of sending a request with parameters(like gender and birthday)
How do I set those?

Also, how can I set key words?

Does it even help? Did anyone see changes in their profitis/ads contents after setting parameters?

I can't find any information about this subject anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for the Location info, I haven't seen any improvement by setting those parameters. Rather, users tend to be afraid and uninstall the app.

In the case of your specific question for Gender, there's an enum AdManager.GENDER with the MALE and FEMALE values.

You should use AdRequest instead of AdManager in the new SDK version, but the idea is the same. From http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html#targeting :

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();

request.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.FEMALE);
request.setLocation(location);
request.setBirthday("20000101");
```

Comment: Ok,but if my program is about diet and nutrition, and I set appropriate keywords,wouldn't the User get ads that are relevant to his interest? Could you please show a code on how to implement the usage of adManager?

Comment: It should, but I've found no way to find it out certainly. I mean, those parameters and stuff are handled in the server. Please see my edit for an example.

Comment: Ok thanks! Although I did see asd that are related to the Apo in different applications.

Comment: Hi. The link that you have provided is not working, please update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is updated code for using latest AdMob in android.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .setLocation(location)
    .setGender(AdRequest.GENDER_FEMALE)
    .setBirthday(new GregorianCalendar(1985, 1, 1).getTime())
    .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
    .build();
adView.loadAd(request);
```

From https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting#loading_an_ad_with_targeting